# The LLM I have imported from Huggingface is running very slowly on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, large-language-model

I'm running the code contained in the following snippet in my Google Colab account

https://huggingface.co/quantumaikr/llama-2-70b-fb16-korean.

The code is here.

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("quantumaikr/llama-2-70b-fb16-korean")
model =     AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("quantumaikr/llama-2-70b-fb16-korean",   torch_dtype=torch.float16, device_map="auto")

system_prompt = "### System:\\n귀하는 지시를 매우 잘 따르는 AI인 QuantumLM입니다. 최대한 많이 도와주세요. 안전에 유의하고 불법적인 행동은 하지 마세요.\\n\\n"

message = "인공지능이란 무엇인가요?"
prompt = f"{system_prompt}### User: {message}\\n\\n### Assistant:\\n"
inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
output = model.generate(\*\*inputs, do_sample=True, temperature=0.9, top_p=0.75, max_new_tokens=4096)

print(tokenizer.decode(output\[0\], skip_special_tokens=True))` `
```

I have a Google Pro Plus account and am using a T4 TPU. When I import the safe tensors via the AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained command, this uses up almost all my disk space on Colab, which causes the subsequent code to run very slowly. However, when I mount to my Google Drive and cache the tensors in there, this also causes the code to run slowly!

What am I doing wrong? It seems unlikely that this code is not capable of being run on Colab.